# Is there really no predefined dynamic 2d container in Smalltalk? Do I have to make my own?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I need a dynamic 2d container and I was suprised that I could not find anything usefull in the Collections. So I made my own in oldskool fashion but somehow I feel like there must be somthing im missing. The whole concept in smalltalk pharo is based on using their stuff instead of having to build your own.

Comment: The whole point of Smalltalk is to let you represent concepts both concrete and abstract in a direct way. Chances are that your need for a 2D container comes from a data-structure approach. Tell us what objects do you want to contain and we will try to give you some advice.

Comment: By 2D you mean dynamic 2D (the size of second dimension can vary), or fixed Matrix?

Comment: I wrote dynamic twice;) I want to store a bunch of morphs so I can display them

Comment: Please explain why do you want to put the morphs in a 2D collection so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: dynamic means the container grows on demand. I thought that was common terminology. Smalltalk is not just a language you have to use the build in stuff or its to light. At least thats what the pharo people say in talks like PharoDays. Anyways if its ment to be or not. I was looking for a growing 2d container. Atm I am working with a colection of collections and its not as convienient as having a build-in @Leandro its just so that I can acces them with idicies. I want to display a grid of them, Simple switch morphs

Comment: @Leandro Caniglia its just so that I can acces them with idicies. I want to display a grid of them, Simple switch morphs. So I can say morph at:1 at: 1 turnOn for exapmle

Comment: Understood. See my answer and let me know if you need further clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you want to have a collection of objects (morphs in your case) arranged by rows and columns. Here is one way to do this

1. **Initialization:** Create an instance variable in your class for holding the objects, and initialize it as:

   ```
   morphs := OrderedCollection new
   ```
2. **Addition:** Place new objects in your collection by means of a method like this one

   ```
   placeMorph: morph atRow: i column: j
     | row |
     row := morphs at: i ifAbsentPut: [OrderedCollection new].
     j - row size timesRepeat: [row add: nil].
     row at: j put: morph
   ```

Note that by adding `nil` exactly `j - row size` times (which could be `<= 0`) ensures the existence of a slot at row `i` column `j`.

3. **Retrieval**: Get the object at a given position in the grid or `nil`

   ```
   morphAtRow: i column: j
     | row |
     row := morphs at: i ifAbsent: [^nil].
     ^row at: j ifAbsent: [nil]
   ```

---

Another possibility would be to use a `Dictionary`, which could make sense if the grid is large and sparse. In that case you could do the following

1. **Initialization**

   ```
   morphs := Dictionary new
   ```
2. **Addition**

   ```
   placeMorph: morph atRow: i column: j
     morphs at: i -> j put: morph
   ```
3. **Retrieval**

   ```
   morphAtRow: i column: j
     ^morphs at: i -> j ifAbsent: [nil]
   ```

Note that I've used associations `i -> j` for the keys. Another possibility would have been to use pairs `{i.j}`.

Comment: Thanks but thats kinda what im doing allready. Thus i asked for a predefined class. You can see here how I set it up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348925/how-can-i-change-the-position-of-a-morph-in-smalltalk

Comment: I see. Then the answer is no, there is no 2D dynamic collection in the base hierarchy. The reason being that it would not add much in most cases and it is always possible to create your own if you happen to need it.

Comment: Ok that`s what I wanted to know. I though I missed something. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. See also the second option I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pharo has `Matrix` class. That's pretty much a 2d container, unless you are talking about something else I do not understand :)

Comment: yeah but is it dynamic? I think it comes with a fixed size and I had to replace it myself to make it dynamic. Thats what im asking for. I also dont want the same number of rows and columns. That was also a bit weird with matrix