# How can I change the position of a morph in smalltalk? 2D Grid

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have trouble changing the position of some morphs. While it is possible to move them from the Inspector with:

```
self position: 50 @ 50
```

for example.

I wrote a function which should set the position of of a 2d collection of morphs.
Cell is a subclass of simple switchmorph. And the class owning this function is a subclass of bordered morph.

```
setCells
| xPos yPos row col |
xPos := 0.
yPos := 0.
row := 1.
col := 1.
cells := OrderedCollection new.
cols timesRepeat: [ cells add: OrderedCollection new ].
cells do: [ :each | rows timesRepeat: [ each add: (Cell new size: cellSize) ] ].
rows
    timesRepeat: [ cols
            timesRepeat: [ ((cells at: row) at: col) position: xPos @ yPos.
                xPos + cellSize.
                row + 1 ].
        row:=1.
        yPos + cellSize.
        col + 1 ].
cells do: [ :x | x do: [ :y | self addMorph: y ] ]
```

I don't get an error and actually all cells are added but all on the same position.
When I try to cast them into the world instead the same happens. All on the the same spot.

I hope someone can help me out here.

Solution:
[the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZLmM.png)

```
calculatePositions
| row col xPos yPos |
row := 1.
col := 1.
xPos := 0.
yPos := 0.
rows
    timesRepeat: [ cols
            timesRepeat: [ ((cells at: row) at: col) position: xPos @ yPos.
                xPos := xPos + cellSize.
                row := row + 1 ].
        row := 1.
        xPos := 0.
        yPos := yPos + cellSize.
        col := col + 1 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not updating the variables `xPos`, `row`, `yPos` and `col`. So, instead of

```
            xPos + cellSize.
            row + 1 ].
```

and

```
    row:=1.
    yPos + cellSize.
    col + 1].
```

you should say

```
            xPos := xPos + cellSize.
            row := row + 1].
```

and

```
    row := 1.
    yPos := yPos + cellSize.
    col := col + 1].
```

Comment: ok yes that was it thanks you are killing it. But for some reason the morphs are all over the place now and not gridlike xD

Comment: ok I forgot to reset xPos aswell now its working. Thanks again. That lesson I learned. + is not +=. Thanks again :) solution added to the question

Comment: @TheFool: If Leandro's answer helped you solve it, please mark it as the accepted answer. Also, we typically don't update questions with the solution here on SO - it's supposed to be a Q&A site, so there should be one question at the top with zero or more answers below. If you really believe your solution would benefit someone else, include it _below_ your original question and clearly mark it as an update.

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how. If I try to upvote his answer nothing happens because my rep is too low. And another options seems not to be available. P.s. im kinda new so. I might get some things wrong. Im open for corrections tho. How can I mark his answer?

Comment: @TheFool: You just need to [click on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) below the upvote/downvote arrows (only works when you asked the question, of course). No worries, everyone starts out as new at some point - I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn the basics. Hint: use "@name" in a comment to let the person you're responding to know they've got a new message.

Comment: @TheFool: no problems, and good to see you figured it out :-)